# I need code of DataManager.dll in Dynamics Ax Pos

Tags: axapta

my customer using Ax Pos and they want to an extra column in Customer Serach page:[image: Ax Pos Page in Visual Studio]

I must add the column in class

but the class inside in DataManager.dll
[image]
[image]

I have dll file but I cant find code of DataManager.dll.

How can add the column of class?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently all code in Enterprise POS is not open.
We faced same kind of issue and had to open a case for a DCR (design change request). It needs to be a standard field with a business justification as it is to be put in standard for all customers.

Comment: Geoffrey, Thank you for answer. We are delete current code in the page and write own code. we are connect POS DB and bring customers.